# Consolidation of query (task) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following task. This task can take a few seconds to complete.

How can make the task below make trips and run faster?

```
class SendMessage(Task):
    name = "Sending SMS"
    max_retries = 10
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_id, gateway_id=None, **kwargs):
        logging.debug("About to send a message.")

        # Because we don't always have control over transactions
        # in our calling code, we will retry up to 10 times, every 3
        # seconds, in order to try to allow for the commit to the database
        # to finish. That gives the server 30 seconds to write all of
        # the data to the database, and finish the view.
        try:
            message = Message.objects.get(pk=message_id)
        except Exception as exc:
            raise SendMessage.retry(exc=exc)

        if not gateway_id:
            if hasattr(message.billee, 'sms_gateway'):
                gateway = message.billee.sms_gateway
            else:
                gateway = Gateway.objects.all()[0]
        else:
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=gateway_id)

        # Check we have a credits to sent me message
        account = Account.objects.get(user=message.sender)
        # I'm getting the non-cathed version here, check performance!!!!!
        if account._balance() >= message.length:
            response = gateway._send(message)

            if response.status == 'Sent':
                # Take credit from users account.
                transaction = Transaction(
                    account=account,
                    amount=- message.charge,
                    description="Debit: SMS Sent",

                )
                transaction.save()
                message.billed = True
                message.save()
        else:
            pass

        logging.debug("Done sending message.")
```

Comment: What does "make trips" mean here?

Comment: By this I mean database calls, sorry